# Is it possible to fetch only the field names from an input flat file using informatica powercenter?

Tags: informatica

I am currently working on a project where I have to fetch only the field names from an input flat file in informatica powercenter 9.6.1. Is this possible? If so, how to do it?

Comment: So, you only want to read the first row from the file?

Comment: Yes first row will be the field names and I want to read that alone.

Answer (score 0):

How about switching to command on session-level Source Qualifier properties and put in the `head -1 yourFile.sth`?